# WebRTC - Streaming video and audio from a browser extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, webrtc, getusermedia

I'm wondering if it would be possible to stream video(only 1-way, transmitting but not receiving) and audio(2-way) within a browser extension. (particularly interested in Firefox, Opera, and Chrome).

I'd like to be able to stream audio and video through the extension, while the popup is active and while it's not (through the background).

Is there any other way I could go about this without injecting code into a tab and creating a connection there?